# How to create and plot a piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a plot of multiple functions, but don't quite know how to format them in python. Say the below example, trying to plot the letter A using 3 functions with certain x values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(-5,-4)
x2=np.linspace(-4,-3)
x3=np.linspace(-4.5,-3.5)
y=2*x+10
y2=-2*x2-6
y3=np.ones(len(x3))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.plot(x3,y3)
plt.show()
```

As you can see, I've had to create the range of x values for each function individually, and also defined each function individually per line. Then had to plot each one independently. When trying to plot say...50 functions, this can become very tedious. Mathematically, there is a simplified easy way to write the above (I.E. Piecewise functions). Where some f(x) is equal to 2*x+10 for -5 < x < -4, -2*x-6 for -4 < x < -3, etc. Then ideally I'd like to be able to plot each one within my piecewise function f(x).

I'm just a bit unfamiliar with the formatting, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you check numpy.piecewise? Did you look at other questions on that topic?

Comment: I did, but it didn't seem like that was what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

For a start you can create a list of endpoints using your formulas in a *for* loop. Then create a list of pairs for the line segments. A good way to assign **(x1, y1)** ... would be  `namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])`.

```
from collections import namedtuple
```

Finally, another loop to plot the line segments.  You can optimize.